# ERROR TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable AWS Lamda with AWS Rekognition on Stored Video (face search)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-rekognition

I am new to python and I am trying to run get_face_search with AWS recognition on a stored video I would like to have it email me when a face is detected in my collection. Stealing from the internet to put together what I require I keep getting the error

> [ERROR] TypeError: 'NoneType' object. Note it is triggered from an SNS topic once the search for faces has been complete. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
import os
import json
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        message = json.loads(record['Sns']['Message'])
        
        job_id = message['JobId']
        s3_bucket = message['Video']['S3Bucket']
        s3_object = message['Video']['S3ObjectName']

        label_detection_data = GetFaceSearchCollectionResults(job_id)


        mailer = ''
        timestamps = []
        for i in label_detection_data['Persons']:
                conf_level = i['Face']['Confidence']
                parent = i['Face']["ExternalImageId"]
                timestamp = i['Timestamp']
                if timestamp not in timestamps:
                    if conf_level > 95:
                        string = f'Amazon Rekognition detected "{parent}" at {timestamp}ms on video "{s3_object} with a confidence of {round(conf_level, 1)}%";\n'
                        mailer += string
                        timestamps.append(timestamp)

        if mailer != '':
                client = boto3.client('sns')
                message = client.publish(TargetArn='arn:aws:sns:eu-west-2:12345678:Notify_On_Rekognition_Results', Message=mailer,
                                        Subject='Amazon Rekognition Video Detection')


def GetFaceSearchCollectionResults(job_id):
    """Get rekognition label detection data by job id."""
    rekognition_client = boto3.client('rekognition')
    response_data = rekognition_client.get_face_search(JobId=job_id)

    next_token = response_data.get('NextToken', None)

    while next_token:
        next_page_data = rekognition_client.get_face_search(JobId=job_id, NextToken=next_token)
        next_token = next_page_data.get('NextToken', None)
        

        print(response_data['VideoMetadata']['Codec'])
        print(str(response_data['VideoMetadata']['DurationMillis']))
        print(response_data['VideoMetadata']['Format'])
        print(response_data['VideoMetadata']['FrameRate'])

        for personMatch in response_data['Persons']:
                print('Person Index: ' + str(personMatch['Person']['Index']))
                print('Timestamp: ' + str(personMatch['Timestamp']))

                if ('FaceMatches' in personMatch):
                    for faceMatch in personMatch['FaceMatches']:
                        print('Face ID: ' + faceMatch['Face']['ExternalImageId'])
                        print('Similarity: ' + str(faceMatch["Face"]["Confidence"]))

                print()         
        print()

    print("label response: ", response_data)
```

Comment: Exceptions tell you which line of code they happen  on. You should add that. Also, your `GetFaceSearchCollectionResults()` function does not appear to return a result, which could well be the error. You need to accumulate the face match results and return them at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It is a python issue not a Lambda issue.

Basically, this issue is raised when we try to get some value from the null

Eg:
res = val[0] # the issue is raised when val is null